# Do I have to have a twiml app to call out?

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I want to create an outbound calling app that works across multiple twilio accounts and subaccounts that I have access to through the API but not the interface. All the examples show going in and using the interface to create a Twiml app, is there absolutely necessary? If not can someone show me an example where you don't need to create one and specifically how to modify this line:

```
capability.addScope(
    new ClientCapability.OutgoingClientScope({
      applicationSid: process.env.TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID
    })
  );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. It is possible to [create a TwiML app just using the REST API](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180928-How-Do-I-Create-a-TwiML-App-). Everything you see on the dashboard can be done via the API .

To do that, just follow this example [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/applications#list-post-example-1) for your programming language of choice. I will add the Node.js example as this is what I'm guessing you're using.

```
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.applications
      .create({
         voiceMethod: 'GET',
         voiceUrl: 'http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
         friendlyName: 'Phone Me'
       })
      .then(application => console.log(application.sid))
      .done();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: So the answer is yes, you do, so I went this way today and it should work fine, just an extra step. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: The answer is "yes" if you're using one of our RTC SDK's, which is what you would use for client-side apps. You definitely don't need one if you're building server-side applications.